# Why Oracle doesn't retrieve data when publishing on IIS on Windows 8?

Tags: .net, oracle, iis, 64-bit, data-access

I'm working with Oracle 10g R2 10.2.0.1 - 64 Bits. I migrated my web application from VS2010 (running on Win7 32 bits) to VS2012 (running on Win8 64Bits) and the app runs without any problem when I'm using Visual Studio 2012 debug.

My problem begins when I published to IIS (Win 8 - 64bits). The application runs but Oracle doesn't return any data and IIS doesn't return any error. I tried to make IIS send errors to the browser and also show detailed errors but my `.aspx` is still showing the page and no errors showed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to provide more info/code samples for us to help. How are you currently trying to do it?

Comment: Is your page executing server side code? Does your final HTML to the browser has any server side code dumped in it?

Comment: You really need to provide more info - can you verify that the SQL is being executed but returning no data, or is there an error occurring beforehand that stops the SQL being executed? Only you can work his out, we can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio (all versions) is a 32-bit process and your IIS is probably running as 64-bit process. Maybe you have 32-bit version of Oracle client installed and this is a problem.

Try to force IIS Application Pool to 32-bit and restart and run your app. There is a setting on app poll for this.

"Enable 32-bit Applications" is the setting name.